# How to speed up a complex process of compositing multispectral images in python?

Tags: python, pandas, composite, speed

I would like to speed up my process.
I have a one month time series which consists of 5 images (Sentinel-2) taken over several days. Each image is made up of the same bands that I selected. After several steps I've transformed each image into into a dataframe and, after, I've concatenated all in a multindex DataFrame. Here is the result.

[image: Multindex temopral-series]

(10 bands x 6 dates)
(dates = %y-%m-%d)

Each column of the first level is a date, each column of the second level is a band, each row is a pixel.

Now it gets complicated.....

I built a code that, for each pixel, I find the three dates in which the values ​​of the B8A band are lowest (practically the three lowest values). Next, between these three, I choose the one with the highest B12 band. Thus, the date in which the B12 is highest will call all the band values ​​of that specific pixel in the new composite DataFrame (since is a multindex, selecting the date brings with it not only the value of the B12 but also the values ​​of the other bands connected to that date).
In the meantime, I list all the dates for each pixel in exact order, so that I can associate them for future analysis.
Here the code:

```
columns = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4','B5','B6','B7','B8','B8A','B11','B12']
im_04Jul = pd.DataFrame(image1, columns=columns)
im_09Jul = pd.DataFrame(image2, columns=columns)
im_14Jul = pd.DataFrame(image3, columns=columns)
im_19Jul = pd.DataFrame(image4, columns=columns)
im_24Jul = pd.DataFrame(image5, columns=columns)
im_29Jul = pd.DataFrame(image6, columns=columns)


# dates = DateTimeSerie  (first level)
df_Jul = pd.concat([im_04Jul, im_09Jul, im_14Jul, im_19Jul, im_24Jul, im_29Jul], axis=1, keys=dates)

#creating the DataFrame with only one band
def conc_band(band):
    return pd.concat([im_04Jul[band], im_09Jul[band], im_14Jul[band], im_19Jul[band], im_24Jul[band], im_29Jul[band]], axis=1, keys=dates)

B8A = conc_band('B8A')
B12 = conc_band('B12')

#definition of the max B12 rule
#return the dates (first level) where the B12 is higher
def max_swir(B12, cont):
    a =B12[cont:cont+1][date_ultima].item() #.item() take only the number
    b=B12[cont:cont+1][date_penultima].item()
    c=B12[cont:cont+1][date_terzultima].item()
    if a > b & a > c:  #For pandas "and" and "or" are considered ambiguous so you should use "bitwise" "|" (or) or & (and) operations:
        return date_ultima
    elif b>a & b>c:
        return date_penultima
    else:
        return date_terzultima

  
#start the composite construction
composite = pd.DataFrame()
dates_composite_list = []
cont = 0
while cont < len(df_before):
    df = B8A[cont:cont+1].sort_values(axis=1, by=cont, ascending=False) #sort the minimum value at the last
    df = df[df.columns[-3:]] #select the last 3 values
    #obtaining the name of the three last dates to use them to select the other bands
    date_ultima = df.columns[-1] #the name of the first last
    date_penultima = df.columns[-2] #the name of the second last
    date_terzultima = df.columns[-3] #the name of the third last
    date = max_swir(B12, cont)
    new= df_Jul[cont:cont+1][date] 
    composite=composite.append(new)#HERE THE COMPOSITE!!!!!
    dates_composite_list.append(date) #here we create a list with the respective date for each pixel
    cont+=1
```

The code, although theoretically complex, works very well. The problem is that it is very slow since the pixels are more than 30 million per image and then I have to apply it over several months. Is there a faster way?